# Why aren't my classes being added and removed as expected?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use J Query `addClass` and `RemoveClass` to set my selected tab class attribute with the `active` class. I added alert to make sure the function fires, and the alert message shows up.
problem is `addClass` and `removeClass` don't seem to be working.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a').click(function () {
                alert(this.tagName);
                $('a').removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");                                      

            });
        });
```

I'm using `asp.net` MVC for building the links, and bootstrap for styling:

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Recommendations", "Recommendations", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Gallery", "Gallery", "Home")</li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">actions
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

this is the HTML code as copied from browser after clicking the link and getting alert message, but none of the a tags has the active class...

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                <li><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Recommendations">Recommendations</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">auctions
                       <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
             </ul>
```

Comment: Have you verified in the browser developer tools that the values you are setting aren't being overwritten by other classes associated with the HTML elements?

Comment: Also, you should restrict the selector on click and when you remove the class. As it is, you're hitting every anchor in the page. `$('.dropdown-menu a')`

Comment: I already tried your code and it is working on my end. Make sure your script is being imported correctly.

Comment: I think that is the parent `li` that need that `active`

Comment: What are you seeing that makes you think it is not working?

Comment: Roy's right. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav

Comment: So this is possibly an XY problem.  It's not displaying properly, so rather than asking why it's not displaying properly, we're asking why add/remove do not work.

Comment: @Roy - i tried to do it to the parent element and still did not work.

Comment: @Taplar - i see the class is not added to the tag in the dev tools inspect element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9f87sanj/  addClass/removeClass work just fine

Comment: for home menu it will not work as it is redirecting to other page. you have add "active" on particular page like on "Home" page add active class to "Home" link

Comment: @Taplar - thanks!
i am actually talking not about the inner drop-down, just about the other tabs like about tag when clicking the about and until clicking something else.

Comment: @DnyanWaychal - you mean whenever i am directing to different page it wont work? (the header is like a layout, just the body renders, you mean i should consider it as totally different page?

Comment: @c.d. you need to find the page name from URL and add "active" class to that link

Comment: Uh, clicking the about link should cause a page transition, which should cause the page to rebuild and all your active class stuff would be lost.  I don't see any logic here that would prevent that page transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like

```
<li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Index" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the answer based on what said @DnyanWaychal that page is redirected to another page after adding the class, so i changed if to influence the right page:

```
$(function() {
   var href = window.location.href;
   $('a').each(function(e,i) {
   if (href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) >= 0) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have a separate class for the tabs. In that case please try the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('<className> a').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");                                     

        });
    });
```